# React forceupdate not updating my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very simply I have a html article element. It has a button as a child node and simply when i click it, it should add the product to my table. this all works fine. however, one problem.

```
addToBasket(productObject){
    if (!this.checkIfProductInBasket(productObject)){
      let productsTable = document.getElementsByClassName("products")[0];
      let row = productsTable.insertRow();
      let productName = row.insertCell(0)
      let productQuantity = row.insertCell(1)
      productName.classList.add('productName')
      productQuantity.classList.add('quantityClass')
      productName.innerHTML = productObject.title
      productQuantity.innerHTML = productObject.quantity
    }
    else{
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
  }
```

I do a check to see if the product is in the basket. if not, i add it. if it is there, i hit the else block and try and do a `forceUpdate`. the reason being is that my `productObject` has a quantity field and i want that quantity displayed on the screen. when i log it, the quantity is correct, however it is not displaying it on screen when i clicking the button. it works the first time as it enters the if block and sets it to equal to that. i thought a `forceUpdate` would force it then to equal the objects current value. why is this not working?

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to bind your method to your class: this.addToBasket = this.addToBasket.bind(this)

This should force the render update on value change as it will be linked to the rendered component of your class. Find out more about all this here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @Diveye i have bound it in my constructor, if i hadn't i would have got a `no function error`

Comment: In that case, adding your class code to this question would be great as this would help us understand better where the problem might be coming from

Comment: @TheWalrus It would ready help to have the component's code. You can redact sensitive parts and post it here.

Comment: your code does not make any use of component state, which looks like a bid misunderstanding to me :)